# Display the <a> from response as HYPERLINK in my web page in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, forms, hyperlink

I'm working with an angular project. I get a link as shown below in the response of api and I'm iterating it in the html.

```
<a class="test" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

I want to show the href I get in response as an hyperlink in my output and it should navigate to the appropriate link.
It is showing in output as a plain text.

I have updated my code in the stackblitz.
working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qxfftw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Response from api:

```
  apiresponse: any = {
    message: 'message',
    response: [
      {
        hrefmessages:
          'i need this link to be shown as hyperlink <a class="test" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>. ',
        icons: [
          {
            icon1: 'hello',
            name: 'hello',
            age: 'hello',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        hrefmessages: 'This is also a href test message',
        icons: [
          {
            icon1: 'test',
            name: 'test',
            age: 'test',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the inner HTML of the tag you'd like to bind the HTML from the response to. Example:

```js
<div [innerHTML]="response[0].hrefmessages"></div>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ydusb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You're welcome. always glad to help.

Comment: Hi sir, i would feel grateful if u clarify me this doubt.
1. If in case, if we don't have an <a> tag and have just  href="https://www.google.com/" also,
2. if we just have https://www.google.com/ what shpuld we do in above 2 cases.
as innerHTML is not working in this case.

Comment: If you just have the data and not the entire tag, you'll need to construct the anchor tag and then bind it as the inner HTML

Comment: How sir,  I didn't get you?

Comment: HTML is just a string, correct? So you'd need to interpolate the values into a string that is the anchor tag, e.g. `<a href="${ yourHref }">...</a>`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the response.
It is working.
Another clarification please.
Can you please clarify me, how to iterrate the same on input type "buttons" ??

Comment: Ask a new question with more details and ping me the link

Comment: It's my new account,  I feel very grateful if you  please help me with this question sir.             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854852/place-every-2-strings-into-an-array-in-an-array-in-angular