# Place every 2 strings into an array in an array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript

I'm working with an angular project.
I have a string like below and i sorted out all the special characters using regular expressions.
Now, I want the first 2 strings to be in suare brackets and the second two in another square bracket like coordinates, and the output should  be like below.
Please help me achieve the functionality.

```
test: any = "((-1.23568 75.87956), (-1.75682 22.87694))"
```

My ts code be like:

```
  hello()
  {
      this.new = ( this.test.replace(/[^\d. -]/g, ''));
      this.newarr = this.new.split(" ");    
      const result =  this.newarr.filter(e =>  e);
  }
```

and my final output in result array is like:

```
["-1.23568", "75.87956", "-1.75682", "22.87694"]
```

Desired output

```
[ ["-1.23568", "75.87956"], ["-1.75682", "22.87694"] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `String.match()` to get each group of coordinates, then `Array.map()` and `String.split()` to divide into pairs.

```js
let test = "((-1.23568 75.87956), (-1.75682 22.87694))";
const result = test.match(/[\d.-]+\s[\d.-]+/g).map(s => s.split(/\s/));
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As of now, we are putting every 2 strings into an array. But, what is the solution if we want to place every 2 strings in between the square brackets and pass the same into a variable ? Ex: test = [[string1, string2 ],[string1, string2], and so on ]. If I want to read index 0 - the value should be test =  [string1, string2] and so on I can read any index and it should cone with square brackets.

Comment: I expect one could modify the solution in that case,  if you add that variant to the question it would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
This function can give you such 'portions' for your new array:

```
pairs.push(initialArr.splice(0, 2))
```

Juts loop through your initial array `initialArr.length/2` times.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-feistel-p9omg?file=/src/index.js)

EDIT: Or maybe you can update your replacing logic for getting not just number after number but pairs (for example `'-1.23568 75.87956,-1.75682 22.87694'`) and then just split it twice.

```
split(',') --> ['-1.23568 75.87956', '-1.75682 22.87694']
```

and then loop and

```
split(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't get your edit answer, can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @chlara check pls [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-tereshkova-cfu6n?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid some complex regex logic and just, once you have:

```
const [a1, a2, b1, b2] = ["-1.23568", "75.87956", "-1.75682", "22.87694"]

const result = [[a1, a2], [b1, b2]]
```

Or if there are more than two pairs:

```
const array = ["-1.23568", "75.87956", "-1.75682", "22.87694", "-1.33343", "3.34432"]

const result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) {
  result.push(array.slice(i, i+2))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It worked.

Comment: All the three answers worked for me.